# How to choose between Node.js and JXcore?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, jxcore

JXcore seems to be improved Node.js. Check this carefully designed quote:

> JXcore comes with a built-in multithreading support that can be
>   enabled on your existing Node.js applications without additional
>   changes... JXcore multithreading may bring aproximately 30 to 50 percent solid performance advantage over Node.JS cluster module. From http://jxcore.com/

I already tried to install it and it does really work. That's all I can say for now, measuring performance and up-time is tricky and elaborative.

So are there real advantages to switch to JXcore and how to make a decision?

Comment: @Mahdi that guy ridicules JXcore

Comment: I just changed my mind after readying his blog post about how easy it was to crack it down. It seems they have changed the way it works now, but still. I'm considering compiling my NodeJS app into the Node.js and V8 itself, but haven't tried it yet and I'm not totally sure if that will protect my node.js source code or not ...

Comment: @mahdi check the blog post comments, product page and release logs.. Seems he cracked something already open.

Comment: We are evaluating JXcore for the code protection functionalities it offers. It is also a good and easy way to deploy one application to a customer without asking him/her to install Node, execute npm and so on. My main concern is about the updates: Node is updated quite often and I'm not sure the JXcore dev team will keep up.

Comment: • for referenced Node, details at say https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js
• for referenced JXcore
•• official site ‘http://jxcore.com/’ {not working: gives ‘Sedo Domain Parking’} as per below GitHub domain is no longer maintained; and its https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://jxcore.com/ reports ‘This URL has been excluded from the Wayback Machine.’ However
•• current details found via https://google.com/search?q=jxcore as find 1 of https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore (its official repo) 
•• BUT that SAYS ‘Nubisa halting active development’ & ‘Latest commit.. Oct 27, 2017’ so 2.1yrs ago.

Answer (score 11):

IMHO, JXcore is beneficial for below use cases;

1 - JXcore works on mobile phones (iOS, Android..)

2 - It can be embedded by a Java, Objective-C, C, C++ app.

3 - MT(multithreading) is a winner for an application spends more time on JavaScript land comparing to IO. Otherwise, there is no significant difference. MT works very smooth since I was able to use a node-js proxy-server solution multi-threaded without making any change (jx mt proxy-server)

4 - Packaging and compiling. (https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/blob/master/doc/HOW_TO_COMPILE.md)

5 - Some of the most popular native modules come built-in with mt support, so you don't bother installing them on a target machine.

6 - Built-in external memory store and sqlite database server. (This one is a life saver on Windows)

I had a problem also. For example, I needed to disable HTTP header byte size check in order make my application running. For some reason they've added extra security checks by default so you may need to update your application a bit.

Update:

[JXcore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore) is now an open source project with MIT license.

Comment: JXcore is already open sourced starting from half of Feb 2015: https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/

Answer (score 6):

Active development on JxCore has stopped - see the announcement on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore#important-notice)

> Important Notice: 
>   Nubisa halting active development on JXcore platform

Though advantages stated above are there, but they get nullified with the disadvantages of not getting the latest NodeJS support as part of it.

Comment: that link does NOT seem to be about JxCore at ALL!

Answer (score 0):

I use JXCore to run Javascript from native Java on Android. It can also be called from a background service such as a SyncAdapter. So you can download JS code remotely and run it in the background. that's very non-trivial to do in native land and can be achieved using JXCore. take a look at this sample: https://github.com/capriza/jxcore-android-sample