# What is the best way to embed a web application inside a native ios app?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, swift

I have implemented a certain video viewer written in JavaScript, HTML, CSS. I want to embed my viewer in a native iOS app written in Swift 3. The problem is that I need the viewer to work offline and for that I need a local Node.js server that runs from within my native app.

How could I do this?

Comment: You can use hybrid app development framework like ionic, phonegap etc..

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38192462/7990095

Answer (score 0):

Drag all files in folder structure of Xcode. for ex. Node.js, .css files and take one WebView wherever you want and load HTML code in that Webview.

Comment: Please let me know if still you have any problem

Comment: I know I can use WKWebView object to display web content but that is the problem, the problem is running the node.js server locally in the native app